# regex for preg_match_all to get only 10 chars in string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Using my code bellow, How can I get results array only for users who have 10 chars in address with preg_match_all and regular expressions?

this is my code

```
$data = 'Maria address is QwMP_jkRkM and lives in Peru, Joseph address is QMPjkRk2ZM and lives in Peru, Miguel address is Q.wMP_jkRljo_hkM and lives in New York, George address is hdiJoW58_7 and lives in Austria';

preg_match_all('#(.*?) address is (.*?) and lives in (.*?)#', $data, $output);
```

Actually returns all matches, I need to remove the results that contain more than 10 characters in their address.

Note: I should not use foreach

Comment: `{10}` - for exact 10 chars (instead of the *). * and ? together don't really make sense. * matches 0-unlimited, ? matches none-one

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: `(.*?) address is (.{1,10}) and lives in (.*?)` maybe?

Comment: @Jeff, '?' makes it non-greedy.

Answer (score 1):

The constraints seem artificial, but this should produce the correct output (if awkwardly) and it does use `(.*?)`:

```
$data = 'Maria address is QwMP_jkRkM and lives in Peru, Joseph address is QMPjkRk2ZM and lives in Peru, Miguel address is Q.wMP_jkRljo_hkM and lives in New York, George address is hdiJoW58_7 and lives in Austria';

preg_match_all('#([^ ]*?) address is (.{1,10}) and lives in (.*?)(?:$|,)#', $data, $output);

print_r($output);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Maria address is QwMP_jkRkM and lives in Peru,
            [1] => Joseph address is QMPjkRk2ZM and lives in Peru,
            [2] => George address is hdiJoW58_7 and lives in Austria
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Maria
            [1] => Joseph
            [2] => George
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => QwMP_jkRkM
            [1] => QMPjkRk2ZM
            [2] => hdiJoW58_7
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Peru
            [1] => Peru
            [2] => Austria
        )

)
```

Comment: This is the correct regex. ty